# Complex plot with imaginary part encoded in color

Tags: plotting, color, complex

I want to plot the complex cosine in a 3D graphic where the real part is given by the surface, while the imaginary part is indicated by the color. Therefore, I tried the code:

```
Plot3D[Cos[x + I y] // Re, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[Cos[#1 + I #2] // Im] &)]
```

which seems to not work properly, see the picture.

[image]

Is there something wrong about my code, in that the #'s are not passed to the ColorFunction option properly? I saw examples where the argument was encoded into the color, and I don't see what's problematic about my try.

Edit: This is what I get using `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`:

[image]

Comment: Add `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` and report back. This is an unusual coloring, tho; people more often use the phase instead to determine the color.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added the picture in my original post. Note that I wanted to obtain something like this http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cos/visualizations/5/02/imagetext/0013/text13.gif, to which the plot is quite similar.

Comment: Yes, those are the colors I'd expect, since `Im[]` is unbounded, and `Hue[]` is 1-periodic. You did not say if you want the imaginary part to be scaled as well.

Comment: You're right. Rescaling the Imaginary part did the job as well. I rescaled with respect to the Min and Max of the imaginary part, this worked quite well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am assuming that this not just (#2&) as the color function.

Here are various ways:

```
f[x_, y_] := Cos[x + I y];
g[x_, y_] := Re@f[x, y];
h[x_, y_] := Im@f[x, y];
scp = SliceContourPlot3D[
   h[x, y] - z, {z == g[x, y], z == -2}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2, 
    2}, {z, -2, 2}, Contours -> 10, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   BoxRatios -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 250];
cp = ContourPlot[h[x, y], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   ImageSize -> 250];
p3d = Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   BoxRatios -> Automatic, MeshFunctions -> (h[#1, #2] &), Mesh -> 10,
    MeshShading -> Table[ColorData["Rainbow"][j], {j, 0, 1, 0.1}], 
   ImageSize -> 250];
p3dc = Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][h[#1, #2]] &), 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> False, ImageSize -> 250];
labels = {"SliceContourPlot", "ContourPlot", 
   "Plot3D with MeshFunctions", "Plot3D"};
grd = Grid[
  Partition[
   MapThread[Column[{#1, #2}] &, {labels, {scp, cp, p3d, p3dc}}], 2]]
```

[image]

To show the direction of change (rapid in purple zones) after some play:

```
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2, 2}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Log[2 + h[#1, #2]/2]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> False, ImageSize -> 250]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! Your p3dc is very close to what I wanted to plot, however, now that I see these sliced contour plots, I actually prefer them, I think :)

Comment: @sol87 you are welcome. I showed a number of ways in case one may be preferable for your needs (and as a check for consistency). Good luck:)