# 3D Plotting of complex-valued data

Tags: plotting

I have some matrices which can be exemplified as
\begin{align}
A=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & a_{0} x+{\rm i} b_{0}& y & c_{0} y+ {\rm i} d_{0} \\
 -a_{0} x+{\rm i} b_{0} & 0 & c_{0} y & d_{0} x y \\
 -y & c_{0} y & 0 & b_{0} x \\
 -c_{0} y+{\rm i} d_{0} & d_{0} x y+{\rm i} a_{0} & -b_{0} x & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),
\end{align}
where $a_{0}, b_{0},c_{0},d_{0}$ are real-valued parameters.
I would like to evaluate the eigenvalues of this matrix, plot their real parts and encode imaginary parts as colors.

Plotting real values of eigenvalues without `ColorFunction` can be done using

```
A[a_, b_, c_, d_, x_, y_] := {{0, a x + I b, y, c y + I d },
                                {-a x + I b, 0 , c y, d x y}, 
                                {-y, c y, 0, b x},
                                {- c y + I d , I  a + d x y, -b x, 0}};
a0val = 0.3;
b0val = 0.2;
c0val = 0.3;
d0val = 0.2;
L = 10;

r1 = Table[{x, y, 
    Sort[Re[Chop[SetPrecision[
         Eigenvalues[A[a0val, b0val, c0val, d0val, x, y]], 
         10]]]][[1]]}, {x, -2, 2, 4/L}, {y, -2, 2, 4/L}];
r2 = Table[{x, y, 
    Sort[Re[Chop[SetPrecision[
         Eigenvalues[A[a0val, b0val, c0val, d0val, x, y]], 
         10]]]][[2]]}, {x, -2, 2, 4/L}, {y, -2, 2, 4/L}];
r3 = Table[{x, y, 
    Sort[Re[Chop[SetPrecision[
         Eigenvalues[A[a0val, b0val, c0val, d0val, x, y]], 
         10]]]][[3]]}, {x, -2, 2, 4/L}, {y, -2, 2, 4/L}];
r4 = Table[{x, y, 
    Sort[Re[Chop[SetPrecision[
         Eigenvalues[A[a0val, b0val, c0val, d0val, x, y]], 
         10]]]][[4]]}, {x, -2, 2, 4/L}, {y, -2, 2, 4/L}];

g1 = ListPlot3D[Flatten[r1, 1], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.65]], Mesh -> False];
g2 = ListPlot3D[Flatten[r2, 1], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.65]], Mesh -> False];
g3 = ListPlot3D[Flatten[r3, 1], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[0.65]], Mesh -> False];
g4 = ListPlot3D[Flatten[r4, 1], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.65]], Mesh -> False];

plotshow = 
 Show[g1, g2, g3, g4, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  Frame -> True]
```

In my search, I have encountered a similar, but simpler, example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117707/complex-plot-with-imaginary-part-encoded-in-color). Their goal was to plot a single function whose imaginary part is known.

How can I implement this way of plotting complex-valued data in my example?

Comment: The eigenvalues are complex valued functions of 4 parameters. This can not be plotted all together because the is not enough space in 3D. The best you can do is to fix 2 parameters and vary the other 2 and e.g. use ComplexPlot3D or Plot3D.

Comment: @DanielHuber, I didn't get your point. Values of $a_{0},b_{0},c_{0},d_{0}$ are fixed. I only want to plot each real part of eigenvalue with the color of its imaginary parts in the $x,y$ space. Thus, for each eigenvalues ($\lambda$) I have a 3D space $(x,y,Re[\lambda])$ with colour coming from $Im[\lambda]$. My presented script already plots Real parts; I just want to figure out how to plot the imaginary parts as `ColorFunction` to my script.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood this. Seer my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for the first Table. We first calculate a grid of Imaginary values, then interpolate these values. To use the interpolation we need to rescale it to 0..1 so that we can feed it to Hue:

```
r1i = Flatten[
   Table[{{x, y}, 
     Im[Eigenvalues[
        A[a0val, b0val, c0val, d0val, x, y]][[1]]]}, {x, -2, 2, 
     4/L}, {y, -2, 2, 4/L}], 1];
color = Interpolation[r1i]
mima = MinMax[r1i];
ListPlot3D[Flatten[r1, 1], 
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[Rescale[color[#1, #2], mima]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you!